# segmentation fault while using oclvanitygen

Tags: vanity-address, vanitygen

I'm running the following oclvanitygen version. The program crashes with corefile.
I'm unable to decode the core file. Has anyone faced similar issue, how to proceed?

Update:

clinfo has the following to say, Could this be the reason.

`Device Name                                   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz
NOTE:   your OpenCL library only supports OpenCL 1.0,
but some installed platforms support OpenCL 1.2.
Programs using 1.2 features may crash
or behave unexpectedly`

```
oclVanitygen PLUS v1.50 (OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020)

Available OpenCL platforms:
0: [Apple] Apple
  0: [Intel] Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz
  1: [Intel Inc.] Intel(R) HD Graphics 530
  2: [AMD] AMD Radeon Pro 455 Compute Engine

$ ./oclvanitygen -v -i -D 0:0,grid=1024x1024 -f comic.txt -o ouput.txt
Loading Pattern #1: 1Test
Prefix difficulty:             16506514 1Test
Difficulty: 16506514
Device: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz
Vendor: Intel (ffffffff)
Driver: 1.1
Profile: FULL_PROFILE
Version: OpenCL 1.2
Max compute units: 8
Max workgroup size: 1024
Global memory: 17179869184
Max allocation: 4294967296
OpenCL compiler flags: -DDEEP_PREPROC_UNROLL
Compiling kernel, can take minutes...done!
Build log:
....
....
<program source>:1218:1: warning: no previous prototype for function 'hash_ec_point'
hash_ec_point(uint *hash_out, __global bn_word *xy, __global bn_word *zip)
^
<program source>:1379:1: warning: no previous prototype for function 'hash160_ucmp_g'
hash160_ucmp_g(uint *a, __global uint *bound)
^
Grid size: 1024x1024
Modular inverse: 2048 threads, 512 ops each
Using OpenCL prefix matcher
Segmentation fault: 11
Grid size: 1024x1024
Modular inverse: 8 threads, 131072 ops each
Using OpenCL prefix matcher
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: You should try with the latest version 1.53 first. Download from https://github.com/exploitagency/vanitygen-plus

Comment: Try removing `,grid=1024x1024`. Or even better just use `-D 0:2`